# webpages fits on all android devices

Tags: android, html, css

I'm developing an android project in which consists of several activities each activity consists of webviews.i used html file and css to achieve this.but my webpages are different in   different android devices.i dont want horizontal scrolling,it must automatically adapt to all devices.how is it possible?can any one find me  a solution regarding this??

my webview.xml

```
   <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/webView" />
```

my java code

```
      WebView web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
      web.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
      web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/cube.html");
```

my cube.html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>INTRODUCTION</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyles.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="section">
  <h2>CUBE ROOT OF UNITY</h2>
  <p>As discussed in the previous section that the cube roots of unity are <mark class=          "bold">1, &#x03C9 and &#x03C9<sup> 2</sup></mark> where <mark class= "bold">&#x03C9    =e<sup>i2&#x3c0;/3</sup> = -1/2 + i &#x221A;3/2 and &#x03C9<sup>2</sup> = e<sup>i4&#x3c0;/3</sup> = -1/2 -i &#x221A;3/2.</mark> We shall now obtain cube roots of unity by an alternative method.</p>

</div>
</body></html>
```

and my css file

```
 h2 
 {
font-family: "Times New Roman",Times,serif;
color: #002671;
font-size: 23px;
font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
padding-bottom: 7px;
 margin: 24px 0px 0px;
 }
```

Comment: try this in the head of your html file, and let me know the result please:   <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>

Comment: i tried it but its not working..i tried this<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=.51, maximum-scale=0.51, minimum-scale=0.51"/> its working in device with 480 dp only.i cant find out an exact solution regarding this issue.

Comment: did you added a doctype !!: <!DOCTYPE html> in the top of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try  putting `name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"` in the `<meta>`-container of the html file. ;)

This shoud resize the document and prevent the user from zooming, so in the end you'll have a document that is scrollable vertically.

Comment: in which line need to add this line after the <head>tag?? i tried it but it is not working..shall i need to implement media queries in my css to achieve this??

Comment: It should work if you just add it to the meta container above the head - at least it works with my device

Comment: sorry.i added it but it is not working.i need to scroll horizontaly for viewing the contents not fits into my device resolution.